# Not able to copy file to Azure file share mounted drive when application hosted on IIS in windows VM

Tags: c#, azure, file-copying, azure-file-share

I have created windows virtual machine and mounted Azure file share drive as **Z:**.
My storage account name is **onegbuploadfileshare** and file share name is **onefileshare**.

I have written a code to write local folder file into Azure file share.
(Code Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage.files.shares-readme?view=azure-dotnet).
Then hosted the application on IIS in windows VM.

But local file not get copied to Azure file share.

My source file path is C:\pubish\Files\1gb.test and destination file path is @"z:\temp\newfile.test" where z drive is mounted drive.

I also programmatically tried with

1. Dos copy command approach
   processStartInfo.Arguments = @"/C copy /a C:\pubish\Files\1gb.test \onegbuploadfileshare.file.core.windows.net\onefileshare\temp"
   or
   /C copy /a C:\pubish\Files\1gb.test Z:\onefileshare\temp\
2. ShareClient approach
3. Az copy approach

But not able to save file to file share in any approach.
Code is working for c:\source to c:\dest file copy.

Did I miss something on IIS or code?
Can anyone provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to upload files using AZ Copy and by creating a share in Azure by following the below steps.

Using Az-copy copied the file to the Azure container.

[image]

File copied to azure portal.

[image]

```
            string filePath = @"C:\Temp\sample.txt";
            string azurePath = "https://storagerajesh114.blob.core.windows.net/sample/sample.txt";
            string key = "Storage Access Key";

            string cmd = $"AzCopy /Source:{filePath} /Dest:{azurePath} /DestKey:{key} /S";

            using (Process proc = new Process())
            {
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/C {cmd}";
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();
                Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            }
```

Created a share and uploaded a file using the below code.

```
string connectionString = "Connection_String";

            string shareName = "share";
            string dirName = "Test";
            string fileName = "sample-file";

            string localFilePath = @"C:\Temp\sample.txt";

            ShareClient share = new ShareClient(connectionString, shareName);
            share.Create();

            ShareDirectoryClient directory = share.GetDirectoryClient(dirName);
            directory.Create();

            ShareFileClient file = directory.GetFileClient(fileName);
            using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath))
            {
                file.Create(stream.Length);
                file.UploadRange(
                    new HttpRange(0, stream.Length),
                    stream);
            }
```

You need to use the connection string in the code mentioned in the below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Copy the connection string and use it in the code.

[image]

The share folder is created.

[image]

[image]

References taken from
[Azure Storage File Shares client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage.files.shares-readme?view=azure-dotnet)

and

[AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#transfer-data)